# Calculate the radius knowing arcs' length

Tags: geometry, circles

[image: where R&r are the 2 arcs and l is the length between the 2 circles]

I have a problem where I know the length of 2 arcs of concentric circles (which are R and r) and I also know the length between the 2 circles which is l in my drawing. Any idea how I can find the radius of any of the circles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let the length of the bigger arc be $S$ and the smaller arc $s.$ you have the following relations $$S = (r+1)\theta, s = r\theta $$ that gives you $\theta = S - s$ and $r = \dfrac{s}{S-s}.$